# jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 - error on navigating to dynamically created page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have been hitting my head against a wall for a few hours now, and still can't seem to get this to work.

I'm making a web application, using a multi page template (having multiple pages in my `index.html`.

**Objective:** dynamically create a new page, and then show this page on screen.

**Problem:** after creating the page, and trying to change to this page I get the following error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child` in   `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:1850:8`

The relevant code can be found below:

**JavaScript**

```
// Add the page to the DOM                
$.mobile.pageContainer.append(page);

// Change the page
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', $('#' + pageId));
```

**HTML**

The page has been created and added to the `<body>`, so I will omit the HTML part.

I think the page might not be registered into the pagecontainer, which gives an error? I have looked, but there doesn't seem to be a pagecontainer refresh method.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

**Edit 1:**

Using the mentioned code to navigate to another page, for example the homepage works just fine. The only page not working is the newly created page.

---

**Edit 2:**

It seems the page I create produces the error. The code which was used to navigate to the page worked properly.

The code I use to create the page:

```
var page = $('<div/>', {
        id: pageId,
        'data-role': 'page',
        'data-dom-cache': 'false',
    });
var content = $('<div/>', {
        'data-role': 'content',
    });
var courseTabs = $('<div/>', {
        'data-role': 'tabs',
    });
var courseNavbar = $('<div/>', {
        'data-role': 'navbar',
    }).append($('<ul/>'));
var courseBtn = $('<a/>', {
        href: '#',
        class: 'ui-btn',
        text: 'testbutton',
    });

// Glue the page parts together in the page.
courseTabs.append(courseNavbar);
content.append(courseTabs).append(courseBtn);
page.append(content);

// Add the page to the DOM
$.mobile.pageContainer.append(page);

// Navigate to the page
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", page, {
    transition: "flip"
});
```

Above code produces the error.

Comment: Have you tried `.pagecontainer("change", page);` are you using jQuery 3.x? Can you add an example of the dynamic page?

Comment: @Omar Note that the pagecontainer functions works for every other page already there after initialization of the webapp. The jQuery I'm using is included in the download package of jQuery Mobile. It can be found like this: `jquerymobile.com > download latest > extract files`. After this in the extracted map: `jquery.mobile-1.4.5 > demos > js > jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js`. I did rename the file though (to `jquery.js`).

Comment: How many pages do you have inside index? Are you navigating to other files other than index file?

Comment: Currently have 3 pages inside my `index.html`. I'm not using any other files than `index.html`

Comment: @JiFus: please note: renaming libraries is an uncommon practice, you may better avoid that, you should also keep the relative path among the different files of a library as well. Moreover, posting the head of your page with renamed libraries is a kind of misdirection...

Comment: @deblocker For some reason the script didn't load properly when I used it's original name, that's why I changed it.

Comment: @JiFus: no worries... if you are in trouble with your development task you will find for sure some people ready to help you - but just to pint out that if you are renaming a file from  jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js to jquery.js it will be much much harder, and for you also...

Comment: Are you sure all tags all closed properly? Without your actual used markup we can't predict the problem.

Comment: @Omar Yes, all tags are closed properly.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/f4CzrchKzHHsQ21GAUWj?p=preview I can add as many pages as I want without any issue.

Comment: @Omar Yes I see, thank you. I will try to see if I can use this plunker to make it happen.

Comment: @Omar See my updated question. Thanks to you I was able to find the flaw. If you write an appropriate answer I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @JiFus I'm glad I've been of help. Unfortunately, I can't post an answer since the cause of your problem is _typographical_.

Comment: @Omar So what do I do with the bounty then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148759/discussion-between-omar-and-jifus).

Comment: @Omar: most respect for you, IMHO i just believe this isn't a typographical error, in fact `ul`without any `li`is allowed HTML - correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Omar:...so, i believe this would be a good starting point to have from you an example of how to _create and test_ dynamic markup. For example: i'm used to create a static page and only after this first time-expensive phase, then i'm concatenating strings. How to do that in a better/faster way without unexpected errors...? I would love to hear from you some advice about that.

Comment: @deblocker join [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148759/discussion-between-omar-and-jifus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue needs to be clarified:

- This isn't a **jQuery** error, this is a **jQuery Mobile** error. The
  error message posted in the question  is wrong, because the
  `jquery.mobile.js` library has been renamed to `jquery.js`.

  By using the standard `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js` the error message
  is:

  > Uncaught Error: Syntax error,
  >   unrecognized expression: :nth-child at jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3

  but be aware, the line number may vary if a custom download is used
  or if the debug version is used.
- Affected widget: [Navbar](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navbar/)
- This error has less to do with the dynamic page creation, because it
  also arises in a static page. This can be easily tested with
  following markup:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
        <!-- no <li> here -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Solution: at least one `<li>` shall be inside the Navbar `<ul>`.

---

Because this question has received many upvotes, here are my two cents about the dynamic creation of a HTML piece with JQM:

1. Design and test the final resulting HTML snippet by using a JQM  **static
   page**, in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/).
2. **If the static template works**, then put the HTML pieces together. I'd
   like to use a simple text concatenation, but this is just a matter
   of personal programming style and preference (don't take this too
   seriously) - at least, if you are dealing with a big template, the tag nesting is immediately clear.

   ```
   var html = [
       '<div data-role="navbar">',
           '<ul>',
               '<li><a href="'+link1+'" class="ui-btn-active">'+text1+'</a></li>',
               '<li><a href="'+link2+'">'+text2+'</a></li>',
           '</ul>',
       '</div>'
   ].join("");
   ```
3. At the end, use `append()` just only one time.

If someone is interested, it would be nice to hear some feedback about the performance of the different methods for HTML template/fragment creation.

---

*A note aside:*

the question contained in the title of this post has been already answered by [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar) long time ago:
 [jquery mobile Dynamically Injecting Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15730558/4845566)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I updated the question title + jquery mobile file for clarity's sake