# Dynamic Page Generation Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a bus finder application. The user inputs a bus stop id the live API is parsed with the ID and the results are injected into a dynamic page in a variable. I want to redirect the user to the results page "#page2" The code is running without errors and the parsing of the API is working perfect. The inserting and of the page is not. Any suggestions? at the minute I am using this code to bring the user to the page but is not working:

```
$(virtualPage).insertAfter($('#pageone'));

$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page2");
```

I think it could be something to do with the id on my "virtualPage" variable. I have done this before with a list based application but had an each loop creating the id for the link with was i and the same for the page id.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dublin Concert Listings</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div class="ui-content">
    <div class="content-primary">
      <div data-role="header">
      <h1 style="text-align: center;">Get Next Bus Details</h1>
      </div>
          <div >
            <input data-type="search" placeholder="Enter Bus Stop Number" id="bus_stop_id" name="bus_stop_id">
          </div>
            <input type="button" value="Get Current Update" id="button_get_bus" style="background-color: #fff;padding: 8px;"></td>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//On click of button this function get call
$(document).on('click', '#button_get_bus', function() {
  //Get Enter Bus Id
  var bus_stop_id = document.getElementById("bus_stop_id").value;
  //If Id is blank then given error
  if (!bus_stop_id) {
    alert("Please enter bus stop number");
    return false;
  } 

  //  This Function post request to API with the given bus stop id
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://data.smartdublin.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=" + bus_stop_id + "&format=json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results) {
      // It returnes json data
      console.log(results);
      var virtualPage = "";
      var str = JSON.stringify(results);
      // Code for parsing json and inserting data in html
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
      var destination = obj.results[0].destination;
      var origin = obj.results[0].origin;
      var arrivaldatetime = obj.results[0].arrivaldatetime;
      var departuredatetime = obj.results[0].departuredatetime;

      virtualPage += 
        '<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="#page2">' 
      + '<div data-role="header">' 
      + '<h1>' + destination + '</h1>' 
      + '<div data-role="content">' 
      + '<h3>Venue: '  + destination + '</h3>' 
      + '<h3>Date: ' + destination + '</h3>' 
      + '<h3>Time: ' + destination + '</h3>' 
      + '</div' 
      + '<div class="wrapper"><a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="#pageone">Back</a></div>' 
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>';
      
      $(virtualPage).insertAfter($('#pageone'));

      $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page2");
      
      }
    });

  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `#page2` exist in the DOM and then you're appending content to it after? Is it an iFrame? I think you should review jQuery Mobile Pages further, since the virtual page should be just a DIV.

Comment: that does make sense actually instead of creating a variable with the page. Make the page and insert the content to that page

Comment: Yes, if you review the jQuery Multiple Page model, you would define your `data-role='page'` div and then append content to it before navigating to that page, the page change should work. You may need to review and adjust some of the AJAX settings used by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery mobile Dynamically Injecting Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730423/jquery-mobile-dynamically-injecting-pages)

Comment: `id="#page2"` to `id="page2"` remove the hash in `id`.